# xpath expression with namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

If I have a XML file like this:

```
<abc:persons>
<abc:person id="1">
    ...
</abc:person>
<abc:person id="2">
    ...
</abc:person>
</abc:persons>
```

Given this, what's the xpath expression will be if I want to select person with id is 1.

Thanks.

Comment: And you have tried... what, so far? Please tell me that you don't just came by to have somebody write code for you.

Comment: Your XML file is not namespace-well-formed. It has no declaration for the namespace prefix "abc".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try searching for the element and using a predicate to distinguish the attribute values:

```
//abc:person[@id = 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2 you could also use:

```
//*:person[@id = 1]
```

if you cannot declare a namespace